# Hide Circle in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am showing people images in circles and clicking on which i am showing their data in rectangles like name , profession, country etc.

when i click on particular person's image, Data being shown in rectangle along with image on top left corner of rectangle.

There is a cross button on top right corner of rectangle, when i am clicking on it, i remove the text and rectangle, but circle on top left corner still persists how i can remove that too.

Below is Jsfiddle link : so if you check on click event of circle i am appending a circle of radius "50"  to g element after rectangle. on click of small circle that's acting like cross icon, i want to remove circle of radius 50.

http://jsfiddle.net/c7UT2/1/

Please find the script below:

-->

```
var width = 960,
height = 500;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)

d3.json("data.json", function (json) {
    /* Define the data for the circles */
    var elem = svg.selectAll("g myCircleText")
    .data(json.nodes)

    /*Create and place the "blocks" containing the circle and the text */
    var elemEnter = elem.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + ",180)" })

    /*Create the circle for each block */
    var circle = elemEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r })
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .style("fill", "url(#image)")



    .on("click", function (d) {

        var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(50,50)");

       g.append("rect")
      .attr("width", 200)
      .attr("height", 200)
      .style("fill", "#E6EFFA")


      .transition()
       .duration(750)
      .attr("width", 500)
      .attr("height", 500)
      .each("end", function () {

       g.append("circle")
       .attr("r", "50")
       .attr("stroke", "black")
       .attr("fill", "blue")
       .style("fill", "url(#image)");

          g.append("text")
         .attr("dx", "200")
         .attr("dy", "200")
            .text(d.info);


          g.append("text")
       .attr("dx", "200")
       .attr("dy", "300")
       .text(d.country);

          g.append("circle")
         .attr("r", "15")
         .attr("cx", "505")
         .attr("cy", "6")
         .style("fill", "blue")

       .on('click', function () {
           d3.selectAll("rect").remove();
           d3.selectAll("text").remove();
           d3.select(this).remove();

       })

          g.append("text")
       .attr("dx", "500")
       .attr("dy", "8")
       .text("x");
      })

 });



})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save a reference to the circle that you want to remove:

```
tempCircle = g.append("circle")
          .attr("r", "50")
          .attr("stroke", "black")
          .attr("fill", "blue")
          .style("fill", "url(#image)");
```

And remove it onclick with the other elements you want to get rid of:

```
   .on('click', function () {
       d3.selectAll("rect").remove();
       d3.selectAll("text").remove();
       d3.select(this).remove();
       tempCircle.remove()
   });
```

If that doesn't work you might want to try posting a jsfiddle, bl.ocks.org, or just some of your `data.json`.

Comment: Yes Adam it worked :). Also Circle is filled with image. and rectangle has background red. Strange thing is red background is also coming as part of image . How to make Sure that circle comes above rectangle?. Can you please help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; if you edited the fiddle to include part of your data.json I might be able to see what you're talking about? (nothing is being displayed right now)